# WordPress show title and subtitle(custom field) for password protected posts at archive without adding password

Tags: wordpress, password-protection, elementor, posts

How to show the title and subtitle(Custom field) for password-protected posts in WordPress without adding a password in the archive?

Now it is showing "This content is password protected" as in the below screenshot.

[image]

And After adding the password it is showing as:

[image]

I want to show the title and subtitle without adding the password as shown after adding the password.

**The posts are displayed on the home page through the widget of the Elementor page builder.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using the following PHP code generating a shortcut.

```
function loggedin_only_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
{
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_null($content) && !is_feed()) {
        return $content;
    }
    else {
    return "this content is password protected";
    }
}
add_shortcode('loggedin_only', 'loggedin_only_shortcode');
```

To use this shortcode you have to insert the following in the editor:

```
[loggedin_only]This is only visible to logged in users[/loggedin_only]
```